# How to populate data in dynamoose

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I'm building an API where a user can make a publication to be displayed on a thread. I'm trying to make the author data to be seen with the publication. This way the author data could be get like
`console.log( publication.author.completeName )`

When saving publication, I save the author field with the value of the user id posting the publication.
Then I'm trying to populate the data like shown [here](https://v1.dynamoosejs.com/api/model/#modelpopulateoptions)

This is my User model

```
const dynamoose = require("dynamoose");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const userSchema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      hashKey: true,
      default: () => uuidv4(),
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    completeName: {
      type: String,
    },
    pseudo: {
      type: String, // Should make check on create and edit to ensure unicity of this column
    },
    gender: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['male', 'female', 'other']
    },
    speciality: {
      type: String
    },
    address: {
      type: String,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = dynamoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

and this is my publication model:

```
const dynamoose = require("dynamoose");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const publicationSchema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      hashKey: true,
      default: () => uuidv4(),
    },
    photo: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      default: []
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    anatomies: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: true,
    },
    specialities: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: true,
    },
    groupId: {
      type: String,
    },
    author: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = dynamoose.model("Publication", publicationSchema);
```

I'm trying to populate the author field when getting all the data like this:

```
exports.listPublication = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    Publication
      .scan()
      .exec()
      .then( async function (data) {
        return Promise.all( data.map(function(pub){
          return pub.populate({
            path: 'author',
            model: 'User'
          });
        }))
      })
      .then((data) => {
        success(res, { data: data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new HttpException(err.message);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    error(next, res, err);
  }
}
```

but the author field is not populated, it only display the value of the author field, which is the string value of the author id.

Help please, I can't figure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Dynamoose v1 is no longer supported. It is highly recommended that you update to the latest version of Dynamoose.

Comment: I'm currently using v2.8.5

Comment: Your link in your post references the v1 documentation.